# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n a_{n+1}$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove:

> If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n a_{n+1}$ converges.

It can't be true, I'm just trying to find the right function.
I'm trying to say that $a_n$ is Leibniz series, but I can't get it right.

Would love some help.

Comment: Try something like $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. You can prove that it's true if $a_n \geq 0$ (or $\leq 0$) for all $n$.

Comment: Also, if $a_n$ is absolutely convergent (since $|a_n|$ is bounded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternating series like
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[p]{n}}
$$
for $p > 1$ furnish plenty of counterexamples. More generally, if $a_n> 0$ is monotonically increasing and $a_n^2 = O(n)$ as $n\to\infty$, then the alternating series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{a_n}$ converges but the series $\sum \frac{1}{a_n^2}$ does not.

For example,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\log{n}}
$$
converges by the alternating series test, but $(\log n)^2$ is $O(n)$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence the series
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\log n)^2}
$$
diverges.

Comment: Sory, but the series with $\arctan$ does not converge because the general term does not converge to $0$, but you do not need many counter examples.

Comment: @FelixKlein Yes, nice catch; I updated my answer after your comment. Of course, $\arctan n \to \pi/2$ as $n\to\infty$, so the series diverges.